# Excel Conditional formatting with weighted total

Tags: excel, formatting

I have sets of values in rows in Excel
First row contains weights of how much each value in each column contributes to weighted total.
Now, I want to mark in each following row the value that contributed to the weighted total the most, by changing its background. I played with conditional formatting, but my Excel skills are modest, to say the least.
So, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the weights are in A1:C1 and the values are in A2:C2, enter 
=MAX($A$1:$C$1*$A2:$C2)/A$1 as the 'equals' condition for A2

[alt text http://www.vulomedia.com/images/12339ExcelConditionalFormatting.jpg](http://www.vulomedia.com/images/12339ExcelConditionalFormatting.jpg)

In words this formula is (maximum of (values x weights)) / this column's weight.

Experienced Excel users may notice that if this formula was entered in a worksheet cell it would have to be entered as an array formula to give the correct value. The trick here is that when formulae are used in conditional formats they are always treated as array formulae; no Ctrl-Shift-Enter required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you are trying to do: You have a list of numbers (they happen to be weights, but that's not important). You want the largest number to be highlighted differently.

Suppose the cells are in the range A1:A8.

1. Select the range A1:A8.
2. Select Conditional Formatting (Format | Conditional Formatting)
3. Enter the condition Cell Value is/Equal To/=MAX(A1:A8)
4. Click the Format... button and set the Pattern to affect the background.

(Tested on Excel 2003 on Windows.)